# How to save data properly into list and then convert it to DataFrame in python?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append, centroid

I have GeoDataFrame containing informations about buildings (Building_Number, geometry) and I need to create another GeoDataFrame out of it - containing information about buildings' center points (centroids) with same columns (Building_Number, geometry).

My idea was to firstly create a empty list and append results into the list:

```
    import geopadnas as gpd
    result = []
    centroids = gpd.GeoSeries(My_GDF.centroid)
    result.append([My_GDF['Buliding_Number'],centroids])
    print(result)
```

Yet this will not work for me, the output is:

```
[[0     61
1      5
2     22
3    NaN
4      7
5    NaN
6    NaN
7     5D
Name: BUI_NUMBER, dtype: object, 0    POINT (21.04572 52.14893)
1    POINT (21.02783 52.07371)
2    POINT (20.97048 52.22921)
3    POINT (20.93536 52.25316)
4    POINT (20.93575 52.25281)
5    POINT (20.93293 52.24256)
6    POINT (20.93444 52.24029)
7    POINT (20.93574 52.25361)
dtype: geometry]]
```

I think I need output like this:

```
[[61, 5, 22, NaN, 7, NaN, NaN, 5D],[POINT (21.02783 52.07371, ..., POINT (20.93574 52.25361)]]
```

because I want to convert it to GeoDataFrame (this, I know how to do).
Is there any way I can append the data to a list the way I want to? Or maybe I can convert it to GDF from the output I heve right now?
To sum up, my idea is:

- make centroids, then create a list containing informations about building numbers and centroids
- secondly convert it to DataFrame: https://datatofish.com/list-to-dataframe/
- and then to GeoDataFrame: https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html

Comment: Yes it is certainly possible, you can use Python to create the datastructures you need. The link you posted shows examples like People_List = [['Jon','Smith',21],['Mark','Brown',38],['Maria','Lee',42],['Jill','Jones',28],['Jack','Ford',55]];
df = DataFrame (People_List,columns=['First_Name','Last_Name','Age'])

Comment: and GDF is maybe always like that, a name key with a list of data, which match by index? df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires', 'Brasilia', 'Santiago', 'Bogota', 'Caracas'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil', 'Chile', 'Colombia', 'Venezuela'],
     'Latitude': [-34.58, -15.78, -33.45, 4.60, 10.48],
     'Longitude': [-58.66, -47.91, -70.66, -74.08, -66.86]})

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you to create the new GeoDataFrame? (btw you have a type in the 'buliding' key there)

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(
  {
    'BuildingID': My_GDF['Buliding_Number']
  #, centroids however those are put
  }
)

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
```

Was exploring this in https://repl.it/@ToniAlatalo/GeoDataFrame